# How to setTextSize (TextView) in dp using RemoteViews

Tags: android, textview, arguments, remoteview

RemoteViews allow me to setTextSize TextView like this:

```
views.setFloat(R.id.appwidget_text, "setTextSize", fontSize);
```

but only with one argument. It will set font size in sp. I dont want the text in my widget to be measured in sp.
I need use setTextSize with 2 arguments (`txtView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, fontSize);`) using remote views. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! you can use this

```
public void setTextViewTextSize (int viewId, 
                int units, 
                float size)
```

**viewId**  *int*: The id of the view whose text size should change 
**units**   *int*: The units of size (e.g. COMPLEX_UNIT_SP)
**size**    *float*: The size of the text

This method is only available since API level 16 (android 4.1)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
   remoteViews.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.price, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 100f);
}
```

doc here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setTextViewTextSize(int,%20int,%20float)